# как сделать удаление класса если пользователь увидел объект

Tags: javascript, jquery

пользователь увидел сообщение оно обозначено определенным классом если пользователь видит его то это значит что класс меняется или как в моем случае удаляется

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    
        if($('.text-sender-unrea').is(':visible')){
         
               

                $('.text-sender-unrea').removeClass('text-sender-                  unread');
                   
               

}
});
```

```css
 .message-block {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-sender-read {
    background-color: #8bda84;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.text-sender-unread {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px #3675d8;
 }
.sender{
 position: relative;
}
.sender:before {
content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    right: 96%;
    border-right: 30px solid rgb(139, 218, 132);
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 41px solid transparent;
}
.incoming {
position: relative;
}
.incoming:after{
 content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 96%;
    border-left: 30px solid rgb(219, 218, 222);
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 41px solid transparent;
}
.text-incoming {
    background-color:rgba(173, 164, 172, 0.31);
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.page_square_photo {
        position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 82%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #b6cada;
    width: 70px;
    /* margin-left: 6px; */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.page_photos_module {
    padding: 5px 0px 20px;
    height: 110px;
    
}
.inline-message {
        display: table-row-group;
}
input.form-control.teo-two {
    /* line-height: 2; */
    position: sticky;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    background-color: rgb(238, 242, 244);
}
.orange {
    background-color: rgba(238, 242, 244, 0.74);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0px 0 0 12px;
}
.block-member {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: inline-grid;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-block">
<div class="message-block-inner">
<div class="inline-message">
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="incoming"><p class="text-incoming text-sender-unread">tyhrgedwsqa uyjthgr4fewq</p></div>
</div>

</div>





</div>





</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как вы определяете "пользователь увидел"? Систем отслеживания взгляда (по крайней мере в браузере) нет. Обычно либо надо мышкой навести, либо определить что видно в текущем скроле. Уточните

Comment: @Crantisz text-sender-unrea').is(':visible'

Comment: Это сработает, если даже этого объекта не будет видно в скроле. уточните словами

Comment: сделал так что объект изменяется по клику